# Type of data in linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data

In statistics there are 4 type of data ; ordinal, nominal, interval and ratio. Based on what i read on many website, in a multiple linear regression analysis you have to use interval or ratio data. Let's say i have Y as dependent variable and X as independent. I have Y = stock price (in usd), X1 = profit (in usd) and X2 = Return on Equity (in ratio scale).

I know all of my data are ratio type of data but according to my guidebook i have to transform my stock price (Y) and profit (X1) as ratio scale like RoE (X2) and i can't formatted them in usd. Is that really the case? And can i mix my data as interval and ratio (i.e Y= ratio data; X1 = interval data; X2 = ratio data) to use multiple linear regression?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Unless this is about a particular software implementation and the expected data types, I struggle to see how your guidebook could be correct.

Comment: Hello, my guidebook is about general instructions to do multiple linear regression analysis and not specify any statistical software

Answer (score 2):

There are by far more types of data than the ones listed (e.g. images that might be represented by multiple 2-D grids corresponding to color-channels, geo-spatial data etc.), although the taxonomy has some value. The regression model you show has continuous (positive) real-valued data as the dependent variable. We could philosophize about whether that's ratio data, when perhaps the price could never be 0 etc. and it certainly can never be negative (if it cannot ever be zero, you could get to the whole real line with a log-transformation).

The reason to transform predictors is that it makes sense in terms of interpretation and/or predictive/explanatory ability (usually based on judgement from subject matter understanding), it would not be based on some guidebook saying that dependent variables need to be some particular type of data. In general, there are not really any distributional assumptions about the independent variables in a regression model and one can mix different types (it just needs to make sense).

Comment: I'm new in this & i still don't get the part "if it cannot ever be zero, you could get to the whole real line with a log-transformation". All i know log-transformation needed if data distribution isn't normal.

Comment: Log transformation **can** help when data are right skewed (e.g. purely positive quantities), but does not necessarily help. For some forms of non-normal residuals (it's always the residuals from a regression model that matter, not the raw data) it can even be harmful. It also changes the interpretation of terms in a model (from additive to multiplicative, because $\log(a * b) = \log(a) + log(b) \neq log(a+b)$).